# Realizar cálculo com “ponto de milhar”

Tags: java

Eu estou fazendo um programa que ao inserir um valor ele realiza um cálculo, mas eu queria que conforme eu fosse digitando o valor no JTextField fosse inserido os pontos que separa os milhares (ex: 1000 virar 1.000), e estou também utilizando um KeyListener para que o cálculo seja feito conforme eu insiro os valores.

Eu estou tentando fazer isso com o `DecimalFormat`, mas estou tendo um problema na hora de realizar o cálculo, parece que quando o primeiro ponto é inserido ele passa a considerar que esse número é fracionado.

Outro problema que está acontecendo é quando uso o `Float`, se eu tento fazer o cálculo com as variáveis sendo Float, depois que o valor chega em 1000 o ponto é inserido, após isso se eu tento acrescentar mais um número ele limpa todo o campo do JTextField, deixando apenas o primeiro número digitado á mostra.

Eu tentei também usar o `DecimalFormatSymbols` mas não sei se estou fazendo certo, vou colocar aqui um pedaço do código.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Teste {

    private static float valor;
    private static float lucrox;

    private static void Calcular() {
        //Create and set up the window.

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Teste");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextField preco = new JTextField();
        JTextField lucro = new JTextField();

        preco.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,###");
                DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();

                dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
                df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);

                valor = Float.parseFloat(preco.getText());
                lucrox = valor - (valor * 10) / 100;

                lucro.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(lucrox)));
                preco.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(valor)));
            }
        });

        Container c1 = frame.getContentPane();
        c1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        c1.add(preco, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c1.add(lucro, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Calcular();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Sem o `DecimalFormat` e o `DecimalFormatSymbols` funciona normal, mas sem essa formatação com os pontos que eu queria.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possível testar e executar o código.

Comment: Esse exemplo já não é esse pedaço de código que eu coloquei?

Comment: Não, nao da pra executar esse codigo. Sugiro que acesse o link que mandei e leia com calma para entender o que é um *"exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável "*

Comment: Editei, é assim mesmo?

Comment: Isso ja foi respondido, é nao é possivel. Nao existe separacao de milhar em double/float.